# How do I keep Chrome bookmarks in sync across accounts?

Tags: google-chrome, sync, bookmarks

I use a couple of gmail accounts with Chrome: One for work and one for private use. Unfortunately, all my bookmarks in the bookmarks toolbar are tied to one of the accounts, so when I switch to another account the new window does not show the bookmarks. I really only use the account switching feature to be able to easily log into Gmail and Youtube with my different accounts. I'd like my bookmarks to be common to all.

Is there any way I can achieve this without exporting-importing my bookmarks each time I add a few more? Ideally, I'd add a bookmark and it would show up in all accounts.

Comment: I use https://www.xbrowsersync.org/ extension to sync between different accounts and browsers. You only need to make sure you are using the same Sync ID and password. It does auto-sync, no registration needed, and it's free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a simple way to keep the bookmarks in sync *between* accounts. However, it is possible to log in with multiple Google Account, albeit **not** on the Global/Browser/Profile level (which is what you are doing now).

In order to log in with multiple Google accounts, go to any Google site, such as [accounts.google.com](http://accounts.google.com). There, you will be able to log in with multiple accounts (usually, there is something like "Add Account" or "Manage Accounts", depending on which Google site you go to).

Once you have logged in with multiple accounts, you will be able to easily switch between your accounts when you go to YouTube, check email, etc. Note that you are still signed in as a single Profile in terms of the Bookmarks, etc. As such, you will always be able to access your bookmarks and such regardless of which account you are viewing on the sites themselves.

For most (if not all) of Google sites, you can switch profile by clicking on your Profile Picture. As a matter of fact, that is also where you can add new accounts.

Comment: Thanks. While it's frustrating that I can't easily sync across accounts, your suggestion to switch between accounts inside each google app is helpful.

Comment: you could export them ONCE and use a bookmark addon like Gmarks or Del.ic.ious, in which you can use a common account for all your bookmarks between any browser that supports that addon

Answer (score 11):

No direct way, but you can copy Folders from `Bookmark Managers` of different accounts

1. Go to top right corner of Crome
2. Click `Manage People`
3. `Add Person` - This is where you will add another Crome Account
4. Now go to `Bookmark Manager` right click on any subfolder from `Bookmarks Bars` or `Other Bookmarks`, select copy (You can even directly copy folders from bookmark bar)
5. Now open new Crome window and login with other user
6. Open `Bookmark Manager` from this new window and right click to paste your copied bookmark folder.

Comment: Chrome may have changed. I can't seem to do this within the Bookmark Manager, but even easier, I just right-click the folder in the Bookmarks Bar, copy, and paste to the other Chrome window.

Comment: Actually, you can still do this via the Bookmarks Manager, but there is no longer the option to right-click and copy. You can select it and copy it via cmd+c or ctrl+c to copy.

Comment: this copies the bookmarks 1 time, but doesn't keep them in sync, correct?

Answer (score 4):

In case if you want to merge the bookmarks from two different accounts, open chrome with those two different accounts, open bookmark manager of both profiles, copy the bookmarks folder/file from one profile and paste it into another profile. Way to go!

Answer (score 3):

I found a Chrome extension (called [EverSync](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eversync-sync-bookmarks-b/iohcojnlgnfbmjfjfkbhahhmppcggdog?hl=en)) that can sync bookmarks.  You'd have to install it for both Chrome profiles.  Save your bookmarks from one profile, then restore them to your other browser profile.  Seemed to work fine for me.

The downside is you have to create an account with them.

Answer (score 1):

So, there is no native feature built into Chrome or any other popular browser allowing you to do this. However, various extensions cover what you would like;

- If you don't want to sync all bookmarks and instead just a select few folders, you can use [Bookmark Llama](https://www.bookmarkllama.com?utm_source=superuser)
- If you want every bookmark synced, use [xbrowsersync](https://www.xbrowsersync.org/)

These extensions also support multiple browsers, so you can also use them to share across browsers or profiles.

Answer (score 0):

[floccus bookmarks sync](https://floccus.org/) works well for bidirectional synchronization, and is available for multiple browsers.  Currently it allows you to sync via Google Drive, WebDAV, or NextCloud.